# Extracting ID3 tags from MP3 over HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, id3, http-live-streaming

I've been having quite a difficult time extracting ID3 information from an MP3 being streamed over Live HTTP Streaming (using the Wowza media server, if anyone is curious). I know that the tags (right now the album tag and the album artwork tag) are being properly embedded in each of the file segments because when I download them manually I can see them in each segment as listed in the `.m3u` index file generated by the server.

I am using the `AVFoundation` classes to do this, and I have it setup as such:

```
- (void)initializeAudioStream {
    NSURL *streamUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlField.text];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:streamUrl];
    self.musicPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    self.musicPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    [self.musicPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}
```

Once my KVO method is triggered, I start playing `self.musicPlayer` and I call `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` on it for each 1/4 second. It is in this method that I try to extract the ID3 metadata.

I have tried everything I can think of on the iOS side of things to accomplish this, including printing out

```
self.musicPlayer.currentItem.asset.commonMetadata
```

as well as iterating over each of the `AVAssetTrack` instances and printing out *their* metadata.

```
for (AVAssetTrack *track in self.musicPlayer.currentItem.asset.tracks) {
    NSLog(@"Media type of track: %@", track.mediaType);
    NSLog(@"Track metadata: %@", track.commonMetadata);
}
```

What's interesting is that the asset always says it has 2 tracks. When I print out their `mediaType` property I get "soun" for the first one and "tmet" for the second. My assumption is that the first track is the audio data itself and the second track is metadata. However, I only ever see an empty array in `commonMetadata`.

I also check the status of the properties using `statusOfValueForKey:error` on the tracks, and the `commonMetadata` key always comes back as `AVKeyValueStatusLoaded`.

Any ideas? I'm at a complete loss here.

Also, I am currently running this through the iPhone 4 simulator running iOS 4.2.1. I can't yet put it on a device since Apple is still approving my company's developer account.

Comment: Can you supply the source code of the module to send metadata using id3 wowza library? In client side you catched the metadata using "timedMetadata"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `commonMetadata` you might want to try using `timedMetadata` on the `AVPlayerItem`:

```
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Comment: I had tried that, too! But the Wowza sample code on the site was wrong and once their support group fixed it I forgot to run through my test using `timedMetadata`. But that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: using fiddler/othersniffer to sniff the http request content to see if metadata is present ?

Comment: I used Wireshark to do that in addition to downloading the media segments manually. The metadata is present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a subclass of NSURLProtocol in Appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

then you can see the response of the request made by your video player